# Hyperlinking in WebAPI

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

Is there any solid guidance for generating hyperlinks for your resources in ASP.NET WebAPI? I've read a couple of posts on this:

http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2012/01/08/hypermedia-and-web-api-design-brain-dump-and-samples/

http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/04/17/HyperlinkingWithTheASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Although informative, there appears to be no concrete guidance from Microsoft or otherwise in terms of how best to implement links for your resources (i.e. object model implemented using DTOs at the service layer). If we are moving towards using WebAPI to implement a true RESTful service, hyperlinking is crucial and I would have expected built in support / guidance for this in WebAPI.

A simple example I'm trying to implement this for is using a Contact entity which has a collection of Addresses and a collection of SupportIncident. 
The class definitions based on the first article I've referenced would look something like so:

```
 public class Link 
{         
    public Uri Uri { get; set; } 
    public string Rel { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}

public class ContactDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<AddressDTO> Addresses { get; set; }

    public IList<IncidentDTO> Incidents{ get; set; }

    public IList<Link> Links { get; set; }

}
```

WebAPI is great at exposing this model over HTTP (xml/json) and the GET/PUT/POST/DELETE action on the resource but in order to build a true RESTful service I would like to know if 
a) Is there inherent support for link generation in WEBAPI?
b) Is there proper guidance for exposing the model above containing links to resources and how should the API handle PUT/POST if a client sends links as part of the payload. Should these be ignored?

Comment: Have you considered Web API's OData support? This has rich support for  hyperlinks and restful semantics that you are looking for. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/01/29/getting-started-with-asp-net-webapi-odata-in-3-simple-steps.aspx

Comment: OData support is currently half baked and does not seem easy to incorporate. Besides I'd have to define an EDM model as well

Comment: What did you come up with in the end for this problem @Abhijeet?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, [Ben Foster](http://ben.onfabrik.com) did a great job on this. See the below blog post:

- [Generating Hypermedia links in ASP.NET Web API](http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/generating-hypermedia-links-in-aspnet-web-api)

The basic idea is that you will modify the `ObjectContent`'s `Value` property on the way out through a message handler. This message handler delegates this work onto registered so-called "Response Enrichers" and each one of them has a chance to evaluate to see whether it can enrich the object type or not.

Comment: I have seen that post as well and actually reached out to Ben about his approach and the lack of native support. The biggest issue I have with the approach is that your logic is now decentralized between Business layer logic, Controller logic and "Enricher" logic. Glenn Block is of the opinion to keep the Link generation options closer to the controller and I agree. Besides, having an enricher per entity will quickly lead to manageability issues. If your model has 100 entities... you do the math :-)

Answer (score 0):

I built a sample application that demonstrates the use of Hypermedia in Web API [here](https://github.com/darrelmiller/ndc).  There is another one here https://github.com/webapibook/issuetracker  and Amy Palamountain has another good example here https://github.com/ammeep/hyper-library.

One of the main problems with using DTOs and links is that by default these DTOs will be serialized out as `application/json` or  `application/xml`.  Neither of those media types have any specifications for how links should be serialized.  Therefore a client requires out-of-band knowledge on how to process those links.

To do hypermedia properly, you need to be using a hypermedia enabled media type, like xhtml, hal, collection+json, json-ld, siren.